# Selected Gridview Row not updated using checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to update a row which I have checked and reload the gridview again.

[image]

I update it using a button and a checkbox for selecting the row.

```
protected void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE JobQuotations1
                                    SET TransactionStatus = @Done
                                    WHERE TransactionID = @Tid
                                    AND TransactionNum = @num", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Done", "Done");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].ToString());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            LoadDataGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

When I clicked the button nothing is happening.

Comment: Have you try using debug? Is there any request to your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].ToString()
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].ToString()
```

with this

```
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text
```

You want the `Text` of row cell, while `ToString` will return the type info of cell type.

Also, the correct way should be to get the cell value of your current row like this inside the loop since you already have the current `row`

```
row.Cells[1].Text
row.Cells[2].Text
```

Comment: tried your code now I'm getting this `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MejShop.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: For that you have to post your grid view markup. Edit your question and put grid view markup then we can find something

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", row.Cells[1].Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", row.Cells[2].Text);
```

Modify your code where you are adding parameters. Also check the query which is sent to database server through debugging. Try running the same query on database server directly and see if any rows are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow item in GridView.Rows)
           {    
             if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells["ColumnCheckBoxName"].Value) == true)
                  {
                     long DocId = (long)item.Cells[0].Value;
                  }
            }
```